# Why does EF not recognize my property as primary key?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-8.0

I'm trying to do a Database Migration on a Testcontainers MySQL Container within Functional Tests with NUnit but EF does not recognize my Id property as a primary key.

```
public class MyClass : BaseAuditableEntity
{
    public required string SomeString { get; set; }

    public required AnotherClass AnotherClass { get; set; }

    public required byte[] C{ get; set; }

    public required byte[] D{ get; set; }
}

public abstract class BaseAuditableEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public DateTimeOffset Created { get; set; }

    public Guid? CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset LastModified { get; set; }

    public Guid? LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    private readonly List<BaseEvent> _domainEvents = new();

    [NotMapped]
    public IReadOnlyCollection<BaseEvent> DomainEvents => _domainEvents.AsReadOnly();

    public void AddDomainEvent(BaseEvent domainEvent)
    {
        _domainEvents.Add(domainEvent);
    }

    public void RemoveDomainEvent(BaseEvent domainEvent)
    {
        _domainEvents.Remove(domainEvent);
    }

    public void ClearDomainEvents()
    {
        _domainEvents.Clear();
    }
}

public class MyClassCreatedEvent : BaseEvent
{
    public MyClass _myClass;

    public MyClass CreatedEvent(MyClass myClass)
    {
        _myClass= myClass;
    }
}

public abstract class BaseEvent : INotification
{
}
```

I've also tried using other data types as int or long, using the `[Key]` attribute and assigning `Id` as key in the ModelBuilder.

Simplified example:

```
[OneTimeSetUp]
public async Task RunBeforeAnyTests()
{
    _database = await TestDatabaseFactory.CreateAsync();
}

public static class TestDatabaseFactory
{
    public static async Task<ITestDatabase> CreateAsync()
    {
        var database = new TestcontainersTestDatabase();

        await database.InitialiseAsync();

        return database;
    }
}

public class TestcontainersTestDatabase : ITestDatabase
{
    private readonly MySqlContainer _container;
    private DbConnection _connection = null!;
    private string _connectionString = null!;
    private Respawner _respawner = null!;

    public TestcontainersTestDatabase()
    {
        _container = new MySqlBuilder()
            .WithAutoRemove(true)
            .Build();
    }

    public async Task InitialiseAsync()
    {
        await _container.StartAsync();

        _connectionString = _container.GetConnectionString();

        _connection = new MySqlConnection(_connectionString);

        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .UseMySql(_connectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(_connectionString))
            .Options;

        var context = new ApplicationDbContext(options);

        context.Database.Migrate();

        _respawner = await Respawner.CreateAsync(_connectionString, new RespawnerOptions
        {
            TablesToIgnore = ["__EFMigrationsHistory"]
        });
    }

    public async Task DisposeAsync()
    {
        await _connection.DisposeAsync();
        await _container.DisposeAsync();
    }
}

public interface ITestDatabase
{
    Task InitialiseAsync();

    Task DisposeAsync();
}


 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, IApplicationDbContext
 {
     public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
     {
     }

     public DbSet<MyClass> MyClass => Set<MyClass>();
     
     protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<MyClass>().HasKey(e => e.Id);
        
        builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
}

public interface IApplicationDbContext
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;

    DbSet<MyClass> MyClass{ get; }

    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}
```

Trying to migrate will always return

> OneTimeSetUp: System.InvalidOperationException : The entity type
> 'MyClass' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to
> use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'.

It's a .NET 8 Project using EF Core 8 and Pomelo EF Core MySQL

Does someone have an idea on this? In my experience EF will recognize the Id property as a primary key automatically.

Thanks in advance

Comment: not sure what EF Core 8 does with inherited properties but you probably just need to add `Entity<T>(b => b.HasKey(e => e.Id));` to `OnModelCreating`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as mentioned i've already tried that.    `builder.Entity<MyClass>().HasKey(e => e.Id);`
With the same result

Comment: Migration has two modes 1) Create 2) Update.  You c# classes has to have property marked as key in all classes.  The you need to perform an Update with Migration to add the primary key.

Comment: hard to figure out without being there. if I had a `HasKey` call and it still said "you must define a primary key", I would look for: 1) am I really specifying the right entity type? 2) am I really using the current build (VERY often the problem) 3) is it a false error message and something else is the problem? then I would try other things, like what happens if you add another Id property to `MyClass`, etc. or what happens if you declare the primary key as something else that shouldn't be the key?

Comment: Construct a simplified example with the exact class definitions and configuration that reproduce the problem. The trouble is that there is something specific to your implementation that is missing or incorrect and you are providing only snippits of what you suspect which likely are not at the root of the problem. Create a DbContext with just this class and your configuration & migration code that still exhibits this exact problem. If your simplified example works then expand it out bit by bit to look like your current code and that should help identify the issue.

Comment: Code-First / Migrations isn't my specialty but MySQL does have some special requirements around using `Guid`. You likely need to include information in the configuration about the SQL type used (Char(16) or Binary(16) /w oldguids=true in the connection string, then if you want it to act as an identity column it likely needs a `.ValueGeneratedOnAdd().HasDefaultValueSql("(uuid())");` rather than relying on `DatabaseGenerated` and EF's default behavior for interpreting Id as a PK. One test might be what happens if you make ID an `int`/`long`?

Comment: Thanks for your answers, i've tried using int and long aswell as making sure im on the newest build, same result. I'll also check the point with GUID and MySQLI've included a simplified example.

Comment: Don't simplify the example, otherwise you end with something that can't be reproduced. What is `BaseAuditableEntity`? Is it an abstract or concrete class? What are the *actual* classes? Post the actual code. MySQL doesn't have a GUID type, so the value has to be mapped to either a string or bytes. GUIDs make *terrible* keys anyway, unless you use an algorithm that produces sequential GUIDs

Comment: Property types are mapped to database types by the database provider, not EF Core itself. Which provider are you using and how did you configure it? Oracle's provider is full of bugs so most developers use the truly open source `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` provider

Comment: I've added the classes. I'm using `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql`. Using the Oracle Provider in previous projects, GUIDs were mapped to CHAR(36). I'm not sure about what Pomelo does.

Comment: @jdweng - Public property `Id` (of type `Guid`) has the `[Key]` attribute and is declared in `BaseEntity`. The class `MyClass` inherits from  `BaseAuditableEntity` which inherits from `BaseEntity`. So the PK `Id` should be visible in all 3 classes  `BaseEntity`, `BaseAuditableEntity` and `MyClass`. I am also wondering why EF does not recognize this.

Comment: Make sure Migration is working.  Migration creates a mapping file from the c# classes.  I do not think you need OnModelCreating.  The msdn webpage says "CAN" which means optional.  Try removing.   See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/

Comment: I put your classes in a new console project using NET 8.0 and Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql provider. I had no problem at all to create a new MySql database having one table only named **baseentities**,  with a Guid Id autogenerating Primary Key of type CHAR(36). (A Discriminator column also has been created to distinguish between MyClass and BaseAuditableEntity type objects, but in reality these last ones cannot be instantiated because the class is abstract). So your problem should be related to the differences between your old classes and the new ones, not to the use of MySql, Guid, etc.

Comment: I didn't use API fluent configuration for the entities...